# Does the touchmove event support multi-touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two squares on the screen. Each with a touchmove event. When I run this on my phone, I want it to return the correct X position of my finger. It works fine if I do it for one square at a time (ie just have one finger only on the screen). But if I have two fingers on each square and I move them simultaneously the X's get messed up. Is this the right way to handle multi-touch x's?

html:

```
<div id='container1'></div>
<div id='container2'></div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#container1').bind('touchmove', function() {        
            console.log("container1-" + event.pageX);
            event.preventDefault();
    });


$('#container2').bind('touchmove', function() {
        console.log("container2-" + event.pageX);
       event.preventDefault();
    });
```

css:

```
#container1 {
    margin:50px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}

#container2 {
    margin:50px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:green;
}
```

My jsfiddle is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/jghzqL9p/

You can run it in mobile if you press the mobile icon next to the 'Run' button.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with touch events, you should use the 'changedTouches' property of event object. It is a list of all current touches, with parameters such as identifier (identified the touch - your finger), pageX, pageY and more.

To get full understanding of multitouch handeling I would recoment you reading [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. As suggested by Maxim you should be using changedTouches to read the multiple touches. The points in "changedTouches" have different meaning for touchstart, touchend and touchmove events.

If you are trying to swap or move the objects then you should be using the combination of 'touchstart' and 'touchmove' to arrive at the final position of the object.